# Setting up a data source in TypeORM yields immediate runtime error

Tags: angular, browser, typeorm

I cannot make Angular work with TypeORM. I put that  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78047316/runtime-error-when-setting-up-a-datasource-for-mariadb-in-typeorm)  some days before. Meanwhile, I've tracked down the cause of the problem.

Now I can present a minimum setup to reproduce the problem. According to my findings, the TypeORM node modules do not work as expected (and as documented).

## Project setup

I set up a fresh Angular project using the following command:

```
> "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npx.cmd" --yes --package @angular/cli@latest ng new typeorm-problem --defaults --standalone=true
```

The resulting project installation on a local development server is runnable via

```
>ng serve
```

under `http://localhost:4200`. This is standard behavior of a fresh Angular installation and displays a welcome screen.

Next, I installed TypeORM using

```
> npm install typeorm

added 37 packages, and audited 947 packages in 15s

122 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Next, I created the directory `src/app/control` and issued an Angular command to generate a data source service:

```
> ng generate service control/app.datasource
CREATE src/app/control/app.datasource.service.spec.ts (409 bytes)
CREATE src/app/control/app.datasource.service.ts (151 bytes)
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {DataSource} from "typeorm";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppDatasourceService {

  constructor() { }
}
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "mariadb",
  port: 3306,
  database: "test-db",
  host: "test-host",
  username: "test-user",
  password: "test-password",
  entities: ["../model/entities/*.{ts,js}",],
  synchronize: true,
  logging: true,  // set to false on production
});
```

Running a test on the main application:

```
>ng test
```

While the `app.datasource` service was not even yet mentioned in any other component, this yields an immediate runtime error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
    at EntityManagerFactory.create (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/typeorm/browser/entity-manager/EntityManagerFactory.js:12:39)
    at DataSource.createEntityManager (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/typeorm/browser/data-source/DataSource.js:403:43)
    at new DataSource (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/typeorm/browser/data-source/DataSource.js:54:29)
    at Module.7752 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/control/app.datasource.service.ts:11:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module.4004 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:90:81)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at __webpack_exec__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:198:48)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:199:126
    at Function.__webpack_require__.O (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/runtime/chunk loaded:23:1)
```

For me, this not what I expect from the TypeORM modules.

---

## Environment

IDE Jetbrains' WebStorm on Windows 10 (19045.4046), AMD FX(tm)-8300 Eight-Core Processor 3.30 GHz

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "typeorm-problem",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.20",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.2"
  }
}
```

---

`tsconfig.json`:

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

---

`angular.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "typeorm-problem": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/typeorm-problem",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "typeorm-problem:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "typeorm-problem:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "typeorm-problem:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

## Question

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to make TypeORM work in a browser using a standard Angular setup?

Comment: As I can see from the code, `AppDatasourceService` is just an empty service. What is TypeORM supposed to do with that ? Do you provide it somewhere ? Then, you create a variable to hold a Datasource but do you use it somewhere ? Also, it seems that you are trying to connect to a remote database directly from the angular app. I don't know if it can work, I never did it before. You will probably need a dependency for mariaDB because TypeORM will not guess how to connect to the database

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle yes you're right, the service is indeed empty and is not referenced anywhere. This is to create a minimum demonstration example. From the documentation I would expect that `export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({<DataSourceOptions>})` is fully sufficient for TypeORM to connect to a database. 
The main question is perhaps your statement "you are trying to connect to a remote database directly from the angular app. I don't know if it can work". In a stand-alone setup without Angular, I managed to connect to that very same database with a pure typescript project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question got an unexpected, yet almost complete answer from [this great recent tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpDcOhhBX_A) on youtube.

**TL;DR**:

My attempt at a solution to the task at hand has been way too straightforward and simple. The real solution consists of a separate database server with its own set of `node_modules` without any relation to the Angular part. The Angular application has its own normal ecosystem with another set of  `node_modules`.  Nevertheless, these two parts can live next to each other within one project.

Thanks to everyone who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

as i can see from  your code you didnt install the MariaDB driver.

for MySQL or MariaDB
npm install mysql --save (you can install mysql2 instead as well)

Comment: you are completely right if it was to create the real thing. I tried to compose a bare minimum to show the problem. I gave it one more try and installed a driver, 
`> npm install mysql2`, but that didn't help either (I had tried this on some attempts before, so I knew that this is not the cause of the bug).

Comment: for a test remove your entities and just set an epmty list []. then test it .

Comment: In fact, there are no entities in that demo. I even tried to omit all `DataSourceOptions` apart from the `type` option, which is required. It's the `type` option that is not available at runtime. As @ArnaudDenoyelle pointed out, it is perhaps not feasible to use TypeORM in an Angular project, but I didn't find out yet.